# Running A PHP Script Always in A Hosting Server

Tags: php, web-services

I have created a PHP script which will send mail by a provided mailing list continuously after 10 seconds, but it works if i keep it open in my web browser, but is there any way to run  this script on my hosting server from itself, so that i need not always keep my browser and internet connection on, this script will work in server itself continuously though my computer is turned off?

Comment: If you have SSH, you can add it as a service... but the fact that it is a hosting service, I doubt you have access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you facing problem with command field,
In the Command to run: field, enter the full path to your script (you may need to check with your host for this).
If you want to run a php file, the command will begin with php. For example, if you want to run RSS Import to update your Pligg feeds, you’d enter php and the path to your import_feeds.php file.
On AN Hosting, your path would look something like this:

```
php /home/[your username]/public_html/rss/import_feeds.php
```

If you want to run the automatic backup script, which backs up your MySQL database and emails a copy to you (see 8 MySQL Backup Strategies for WordPress Bloggers (And Others), strategy #7), you’d enter /bin/sh (since this is a shell script), and the path to your script.
On AN Hosting, your path would look something like this:

```
/bin/sh /home/[your username]/etc/upstart_cron_backup.sh
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Run this as a daemon or as a cron. For cron you can run it as low as every 1 min. Cron does not support bellow that.  The cron entry will look like this,

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *  *   *   *    /usr/bin/php /path/to/project/file.php
```

For daemon basically you run this script from command line. In the script you run a while loop with 10 second sleep.

```
while(true){
    // do stuff
    sleep(10);
}
```

Daemon solution is more flexible but hard to implement. For this you must deal with [signal handling](https://www.php.net/pcntl) to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or `KILL` signal, [forking dameon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon), logging.

Comment: If this is helpful up-vote. If this solves your problem *accept* it.

Comment: okay, in my cpanel under "cron job creating page" i have found this http://i.stack.imgur.com/zD02l.png so after configuring cron job time is that i need to put the script url in command field..

Comment: @Max I am not familiar with cpanel cron setup. See my answer. In the cron code snippet there is a comment describing each of month, hour etc. And `*` means every. So when m is `*` it means every minute. Hope it helps.

Comment: if everything was ok then why its not working, i mean the script may not running after every 15 minutes,, here is the screenshot of cpanel, http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1V29.png  see the red highlighted and tell me how should it work perfectly? Thanks

Comment: @MaxMuller **command is wrong**. You should pass it like the *command* command in my example.  To pass the `soft` parameter pass it as argument to `index.php` and Inside `index.php` get the value of `soft` from [`$argv`](http://bd1.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array.

Comment: ok, i have changed the `command` path to `/prijom/cron/index.php` is that ok?

Comment: Did you put `/usr/bin/php`? If not it wont work. Its recommended to use `/usr/bin/env php /path/to/file.php` though

Comment: Thanks bro , i think it should be like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/goJeR.png else please give a example what i should put in command field .. Thanks again

Comment: @MaxMuller please see the example of **this** answer. There is space in between. Dont you understand the example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cron job for this. Cron job can run on regular intervals set by you.

Comment: it means it will run any PHP script? Will you refer any articles, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can run it via cron...

SSH to your hosting provider
and go to your crontab, using `crontab -e`

and set a cron every set amount of time which will use wget.

```
wget [options] [url]
```

search google for crons on how to do this properly

EDIT: if you don't have access to SSH, and you're using windows, you can set a scheduled task, which is the crippled brother of the cron job. you can run a php script which will simulate wget. I suggest running a scheduled task to a *.bat file which run php via console

doThis.bat

```
php [script-location]
```